# Masstransit check if last sent message received

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit

I have multiple Hosted services in asp.net core solution. Each hosted service  as publisher sends multiple messages to Rabbit Mq via Masstransit. All messages have the same contract. Publisher knows if message is last for this day or not.  I need that consumer see that message it got is last.
What is best way of doing this?
I think that i need to store in contract nullable DateTime with payload, meaning that if filled - the message is last for this date from certain sender.

Comment: If the publisher knows that it’s sending the last message, just add that information to the message?

Comment: Yes, it think so. But there's another way - to publish message with messageId of last sent message.